# Как выключать методы класса в зависимости от типа шаблона класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++11, c++17, sfinae

Как я могу выключить метод Get если T = void?

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
  T& Get();
private:
  T* m_data;
}
```

Comment: Выключить - никак. Вы можете сделать специализацию шаблона по тип `void*`. А типом `void` параметризовать шаблоны нельзя.

Comment: В С++20 - `requires`.

Comment: `static_assert` в любом стандарте.

Comment: @DmitryK .. в смысле нельзя? https://godbolt.org/z/GdEn3a7ro

Comment: @AlexGlebe Извиняюсь, похоже ошибся. Значит можно. Исправил в ответе, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Выключить - никак. Вы можете сделать специализацию шаблона типом `void`.

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
  void Get() { cout << "1 template " << endl; };
private:
  T* m_data;
};

template<>
class A<void> {
public:
  void Print() { cout << "void template " << endl; };
private:
 void* m_data;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a1;
    a1.Get();
    
    A<void> a2;
    a2.Print();
}
```

Comment: если  параметр  void*, тогда m_data должен иметь тип void**,  по шаблону

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `void*` только потому, что `void` использовать нельзя. Я думаю в этой специализации вообще указателя не будет, т.к. нужно убрать функцию `Get()`. Там же параметр шаблона не используется далее в теле класса. Указатель можно сделать любого типа, какого захочется. А вообще - слишком мало данных в вопросе, не понятно что требуется.